# NServiceBus 2.0.0.1219 on .NET Framework 3.5

Tags: nservicebus

Is it possible to run NServiceBus build 2.0.0.1219 with .NET Framework 3.5 or does it *have* to run on .NET Framework 4.0? If it's possible, are there and features that don't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nsb 2.0 is compatible with both net3.5 and net4.0